# How to select an array within an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I am trying to perform some array-ception here: Array within an array. I have a string forms which pass on hidden values to the next form. One of these forms submits an array of checkbox values to another form. That form then submits all previous forms into a database. It's working great except for one problem. When passing the array of checkboxes through another form, it puts the array into another array. I want to select the nested array and store it in a local variable. The array is called interests

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => movies [1] => art [2] => cars [3] => business [4] => comedy [5] => technology ) )
```

Right now my array looks like the array above. When I add [0] to $_POST['interests'] like so:

```
$int = $_POST['interests'][0];
```

It successfully stores the second array into the variable int. Problem is that it stores it as a string and not an array. It still looks like an array when I echo it out though

```
Array ( [0] => movies [1] => art [2] => cars [3] => business [4] => comedy [5] => technology )
```

How do I store the nested array in a variable. Or how do I turn the above string into an array.

Thank you

Comment: I've never heard of a POST variable containing a string like that. I think you're confused.

Comment: Are you echoing it or using `print_r()`?

Comment: And if there is something that's formatting the input that way, I suggest you change it. Parsing that format is not reliable, it doesn't use unique delimiters. Use JSON instead, for instance.

Comment: @Bamar When I echo the the full array I use print_r. When I echo the second array I can use both

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm assuming you have checkbox sets with names like `name="checkbox_name[]". That should work and your output looks correct. I don't understand what you mean by gets stored as a string?

Comment: @Barmar The POST variable has an array in it that contains another array. I am trying to store the array that is inside of the array in a variable

Comment: The problem is that it's not an array, it's a string that contains the output of `print_r()`. There's no easy way to turn that back into an array.

Comment: You should find the code that's creating the form and putting that formatting into the values, and change it to use something that can be decoded properly.

Comment: @Gohn67 You are correct. I am doing that. But I pass that input as a hidden value into another form which in return submits to a PHP page. When I pass the array through the second form, it nests it into another array like shown above. When I target the nested array like this: `$_POST['interests'][0];` It stores the nested array as a string in the variable int. I know this because I perform an `in_array` function next and it throws me an array saying that the second parameter is a string. Also `echo` doesn't work on arrays.

Comment: @user3112869 Ok that makes sense. Then you should do what Barmar suggested. JSON is probably the best option. Then you can use `json_decode` in PHP side. On HTML/JS side, you can use `JSON.stringify` I think.

Comment: I can probably help you better if you provide some sample/example code for the frontend html in jsFiddle.

Comment: Your explanation is very confused. It takes more time to understand it than to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean (and it's a huge if), you might use the following:

Original page:

```
<form method="POST" ... >
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='movies'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='art'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='cars'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='business'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='comedy'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='technology'>
</form>
```

Intermediate page:

```
<?php
function pass_previous_data ()
{
    foreach ($_POST['passable'] as $name => $block)
    foreach ($block as $value)
    {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='passable[$name][]' value='$value'>";
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" ... >

    // by default, form fields will not be forwarded
    <input type='text' name='added_data' value='whatever'>

    // inject previous data as hidden fields
    <?php pass_previous_data (); ?> 

    // add more forwardable data
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='English'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='Español'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='Deutsch'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='Русский'>
</form>
```

The final page should see the whole packet of selected values as an array.

The system allows you to forward data across multiple pages by declaring input names as `passable`.
It makes retrieving data pretty straightforward with minimal PHP code.

All this being said, it's a pretty inefficient way of passing data around:
you generate a whole hidden HTML input to pass each single value.

You could encode your arrays with Json or PHP serialization mechanism instead, but I suppose you have your reasons to do otherwise.

---

Here is a one-page working demo of the above example (a little obfuscated by PHP/HTML blending though)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<?php
// recreate hidden fields to forward previous post data
function pass_previous_data ()
{
    foreach ($_POST['passable'] as $name => $block)
    foreach ($block as $value)
    {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='passable[$name][]' value='$value'>";
    }
}
if (!isset($_POST['page']))
{ // first page
?>

<body onload='document.getElementById("post").submit();'>
    <form method="POST" id="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='page' value='2'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='movies' checked>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='art' checked>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='cars'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='business'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='comedy'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[interests][]' value='technology' checked>
    </form>
</body>

<?php } else switch ($_POST['page']) {
case '2':  // second page 
?>

<body onload='document.getElementById("post").submit();'>
    <form method="POST" id="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='page' value='3'>
        <?php pass_previous_data (); ?>

        <input type='text' name='added_data' value='whatever'>

        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='English' checked>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='Español'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='Deutsch' checked>
        <input type='checkbox' name='passable[languages][]' value='Русский' checked>

    </form>
</body>

<?php break; 
case '3': 
    // final page
    echo"<pre>";print_r ($_POST);echo"</pre>";
    break;
}
?>
```